# Trying to install Postgres 9.3 in a non-LTS version of Ubuntu, how do I go?

Tags: apt, postgresql

I'm trying to install Postgres 9.3 with the instructions [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt). But the install is failing.

```
[ubuntu:~]$ lsb_release -c
Codename:   raring
[ubuntu:~]$ 

[ubuntu:~]$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list 
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ raring-pgdg main
[ubuntu:~]$

[ubuntu:~]$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                                     
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                                 
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                                                                                      
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                                                                                         
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources                                                                                     
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages                                                           
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages                                                       
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en                                                           
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en                                                       
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources                                                          
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources                                                      
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                   
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                               
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en                                                   
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en                                               
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US                                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg                                                                       
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org raring-pgdg Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org raring-pgdg Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Err http://apt.postgresql.org raring-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org raring-pgdg/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org raring-pgdg/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/raring-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
[ubuntu:~]$

[ubuntu:~]$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.3'
[ubuntu:~]$
```

I've also tried putting these lines in /etc/apt/sources.list. But that doesn't work either.

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Amy reason to not install Postgres from Ubuntu's repositories? The repository you added only provides packages for older versions of Ubuntu. Read the page you linked yourself in your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read the [FAQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ#I_am_using_a_non-LTS_release_of_Ubuntu), it answers your FAQ:

> ## I am using a non-LTS release of Ubuntu
>
> We chose to support only the LTS (long term support) releases of
>   Ubuntu because otherwise we'd need to support too many distributions
>   in parallel. Generally, you can use the packages from the LTS release
>   that predates your release, i.e. **on raring (13.04), you would use
>   precise-pgdg (12.04).**
>
> There is a known incompatibility between 12.04 and later releases
>   involving the "logrotate" package. Possible workarounds are:
>
> - use the logrotate package from precise, or
> - uninstall logrotate.
>
> We are looking into providing a nicer solution for this problem.